# Is it necesarry to pass value to the instance variable through constructor of the class?

Tags: python

I learned python class today. Is it necessary to pass value to the variable through constructor? It seesm that I can define a class and pass value to the instance variable directly.

```py
>>> class a():
        def _init_(self, food):
            self.food = food    
>>> A =a()
>>> A.food = 4
>>> print(A.food)
4
```

Comment: No, it is not *necessary*. As you yourself have demonstrated. A note about terminology, you aren't "passing a value directly", you are "assigning to the attribute" directly on the instance. NOTE: You've misspelled `__init__`, otherwise, given your funciton signature, which requires a `food` argument, `A = a()` would have thrown an error.

Comment: Final stylistic note, in Python, it is conventional to use UpperCase for the *class name*, so `class A: ...` and use lower_case for regular variables, so `a = A()`.

Comment: See [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) in PEP 8.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is like a normal function. You have to pass the function as many variables as it expects, but you can designate default values that make it so that you don't have to explicitly pass them:

```
class A():
   def __init__(self, food):
        self.food = food

a = A()
# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'food'
```

```
class A():
   def __init__(self, food="default_food"):
        self.food = food

a = A()
print(a.food)
# 'default_food'
```

In your example, you mistyped `__init__` (there are two underscores on each side, not one, so the method is never getting called).

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the answer above, you have typed incorrectly when you called the constructor. There are two underscores on either side of init `__init__`

What I would like to add is the reason your code was working:

- You are creating a new attribute '**food**' for the **A** object and
  assigning it with a value **4**. This means for a new instance of the class the value will not be there.

  `B = a()`

  `B.food = 4 \\Error`
- If you don't define `__init__` method, it by default calls the one in 
  the base class `object`. That is the reason, in spite of mistyping init the code worked.